# Show if the apartment or car is available or unavailable during dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

My company runs a schedule for our subcontractors. We have multiple apartments & cars and need to keep track of who is in each apartment and when they are coming and going. Right now the spreadsheet tracks to make sure we don't have any overlaps in apartments or vehicles. I now am wondering if it would be possible to show "when" the apartment or car will be available next.

For example:
In column B, it would show that the car or apartment is available next on date "12/21/21".

Please see example spreadsheet here.
[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvXmIrgzYYeL3F2BwJTTgq4k-a-tLKSRdF7Wsn13daU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you for any and all help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 QUERY(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FILTER(FLATTEN(I3:J&"×"&L3:L+1), 
 NOT(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(I3:J&"×"&K3:K), FLATTEN(I3:J&"×"&L3:L+1)))), 
 "where not Col1 matches '^×.*|.*×1$'"), " ", "♥"), "×"), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), " "), "♥", " "), 
 SEQUENCE(1, 5, 2), 0)*1))))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mjMNdMJkAUdL_uWrKPG_lGwl6wUb9lGArMfUhHGstdg/copy)

Comment: This is close... I need it to say that the car will be unavailable between 12/18/21 - 12/30/21. As of now it is just showing the available dates.

Im not even sure if its possible but you are on the right track at least. You have way more knowledge than I do so thanks for helping on this or at least giving it a try.

Comment: @BlakeRindlisbacher so instead of "next available date" you want "date range of unavailability" ??